# Repair RJ45 socket after plugging in RJ11

Tags: router, port, modem, rj-45, rj-11

**Background**

My family member tried to plug a RJ11 into the RJ45 sockets on my modem and router.  Now my internet doesn't work as well as it did before.

**What I know**

I read that that the RJ11 may have caused this by "pushing pin 1 and pin 8 so far into the housing that they may never return to their former positions when the RJ11 connector is removed" (https://www.lynxnetworks.co.uk/rj11-plug-into-and-rj45-socket/).

**Question**

Is there a way to fix pins 1 and 8 (assuming that's the issue)?

---

Thanks all.

Comment: If the ISP owns it, and it is not the latest model you may be able to get a newer model from your ISP (this works with my ISP, YMMV)

Answer (score 2):

Get magnifying glass & torch… see what damage they did.

With the power off, use a pin/cocktail stick/watch screwdriver/needlenose pliers to try straighten it. If it's truly mashed, then your next move depends on who actually owns it.

If it doesn't look physically damaged, the contacts might just be dirty. Try a can of contact cleaner. Spray. Insert [correct] plug. Push/pull, with the retaining clip pressed in, a dozen times. Allow to evaporate - better safe than sorry on time to wait, some contact cleaner is itself conductive until dry. Re-test.